# Xamarin BeginInvokeOnMainThread without Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Sorry for what I'm sure will turn out to be a very stupid question..

I am using Android UI not Xamarin Forms for the presentation layer in my Xamarin app, but I want to use the Activity.RunOnUIThread (from Android), which all Xamarin docs suggests is Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (from the Xamarin.Forms) project. Obviously I don't have this available since I don't have a reference on the xamarin.forms project.

Where do I find the run-on-ui-thread mechanism in Xamarin if I don't want to use Forms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Android:

Android `Activity`s have a `RunOnUiThread` method that you can use:

```
RunOnUiThread  ( () => {
    // manipulate UI controls
});
```

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread/p/Java.Lang.IRunnable/

### iOS:

```
InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {  
    // manipulate UI controls
});
```

Comment: Whats the windows equivalent? I have code that is shared between Android version and Windows version.

Comment: @StephenPrice You did not say what type of Windows project, On UWP you can use CoreDispatcher : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunAsync_Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcherPriority_Windows_UI_Core_DispatchedHandler_

Comment: It's not a UWP app. It runs on Windows 7. Looking at the project references shows System.Windows.Forms. Not seen anything like it (given it shares a lot of code with a Xamarin.Android app). Most of the app is written using OpenTK. The main page of the app inherits from Form (so yeah, definitely looks like a Windows.Forms app.)

Comment: @StephenPrice You are looking for `BeginInvoke` for Windows.Forms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this from your PCL / shared code and everywhere else in your project. You have two options doing this.

**Cross platform way, using the native mechanisms**

- add this to PCL

  ```cs
  public class InvokeHelper
  {
      public static Action<Action> Invoker;

      public static void Invoke(Action action)
      {
          Invoker?.Invoke(action);
      }
  }
  ```
- add this to iOS (e.g. AppDelegate)

  ```cs
  public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
  {
      // ...

      InvokeHelper.Invoker = InvokeOnMainThread;
      return true;
  }
  ```
- add this to Android (e.g. your application class)

  ```cs
  [Application]
  class MainApplication : Application
  {
      protected MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
      {
      }

      public override void OnCreate()
      {
          base.OnCreate();
          InvokeHelper.Invoker = (action) =>
          {
              var uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
              uiHandler.Post(action);
          };
      }
  }
  ```

And then you can call from your shared code

```cs
InvokeHelper.Invoke(() => DoSomething("bla"));
```

**Complete cross platform way**

You can implement `InvokeHelper` cross platform, too.

```cs
public class InvokeHelper
{
    // assuming the static initializer is executed on the UI Thread.
    public static SynchronizationContext mainSyncronisationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public static void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        mainSyncronisationContext?.Post(_ => action(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution, however since I'm doing mostly a more simple solution and only need it in pure android for now I've gone with Sushi's answer below. I've upvoted your suggestion though, as I think that it's a really good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example obtained from the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/writing_responsive_applications/):

```
public class ThreadDemo : Activity
{
  TextView textview;

  protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
  {
      base.OnCreate (bundle);
      // Create a new TextView and set it as our view
      textview = new TextView (this);
      textview.Text = "Working..";
      SetContentView (textview);
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (o => SlowMethod ());
  }

  private void SlowMethod ()
  {
      Thread.Sleep (5000);
      RunOnUiThread (() => textview.Text = "Method Complete");
  }
}
```

Basically, if you want to run more than one line of code, you can do this:

```
RunOnUiThread(()=>{
  MethodOne();
  MethodTwo();
});
```

[source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4736/using-of-runonuithread)