# Xamarin: How to let UI redraw while performing long-running operation on UI thread (without the use of async/await)

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin, .net-standard, ui-thread

I am (for reasons) forced to perform a long-running operation on the UI thread of my xamarin forms (NetStandard) application.  During this operation, I would like to update the UI to give the user feedback on progress.  I can make changes to the UI, but the UI will not redraw as I cannot return the instruction pointer to the OS by using await/async.

Is there any way I can process messages on the UI thread without using async/await.  In the old Win32 days I think Translate/DispatchMessage could be used to keep the message pump going in long-running operations, and this is similar to what I need.

Background:  I have a interface defined and called by the android OS that runs on my UI thread.  It is important that we return the result of this long-running operation from this service.  Because the interface is not defined as async I cannot use await to let the IP return to the OS.  If I did the function would immediately return (without the results being fetched) and continue executing (ie, it would fail).  I can't change these circumstances.

```
// The following class is called directly by the AndroidOS
class CloudHostCardService : HostApduService
{
    // The following method is called by the AndroidOS on the UI thread
    public override byte[] ProcessCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras)
    {
        ViewModels.MainPageViewModel.SetStatus("Processing Cmd");  // <-- updates UI
        return processor.ProcessCommand(commandApdu); // <-- Long running operation
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to trigger a redraw (pump messages in Win32 speak)?

Comment: Are you using Forms or a native Android app? Via Forms, use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` Or natively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619293/xamarin-begininvokeonmainthread-without-xamarin-forms/36619574#36619574

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question wasn't clear.  I'm already on the main thread, and am forced to complete a long-running operation there.  I can manipulate UI elements, but the system won't redraw because I am holding the instruction pointer for that thread

Comment: Do your "compute" processing on another thread. (As a side note, why can you not add `async` to the callback method?)

Comment: I can't do either of those things, because the callback is called by the Android OS (in response to an NFC trigger), and the callback is not defined as async.

Comment: You can "just" add `async` to the method. You should update your question with the code in question, also you can perform a `Task.Run` in that method, that processes what you need on a background thread and then do a RunOnUiThread to update the ui

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I am implementing an interface defined by the OS.  You cannot call an async function from synchronous code.  I cannot modify this function to be async (If I did, the calling code would immediately continue execution if I 'await'ed, which is an error)

Comment: Yes, I can define the method as async, but all that does not change the underlying call to the function, which is not async - and will not 'await' my call.  I cannot return the IP to the OS this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817558/why-does-c-sharp-allow-making-an-override-async

Comment: To clarify: I need to return the result of the long running op.  Because the AndroidOS does not 'await' the call to this interface, I have to block the thread to do the fetch in order to return the result.  Similar to any time when a synchronous method calls an async method

Comment: I see you added a code sample and you are using  HostApduService, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HostApduService allows you to return `null` from `ProcessCommandApdu` and then later use SendResponseApdu to supply the `ResponseApdu`.

> This method is running on the main thread of your application. If you cannot return a response APDU immediately, return null and use the sendResponseApdu(byte[]) method later.

#### Example:

```
public class SampleHostApduService : HostApduService
{
    public override void OnDeactivated([GeneratedEnum] DeactivationReason reason)
    {
    }

    public override byte[] ProcessCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras)
    {
        // Update your UI via your viewmodel.

        // Fire and forget
        Task.Run(() => {
            this.SendResponseApdu(processor.ProcessCommand(commandApdu));
         });

        // Return null as we handle this using SendResponseApdu
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh.my.god.  Thanks for the RTFM reminder.  I've read the docs so many times I didn't even think to go there for the answer.  I'll be testing this out as soon as local opens.

Comment: yup works a charm.  Thanks a tonne Mr Sushi, hope the hangover gets better

Comment: @FrozenKiwi NP, Glad to help 